# Mac OS CodeBlocks debugger

Tags: c++, macos, debugging

I just installed CodeBlocks on Mac OS and I ran into a problem when debugging.

> ERROR: You need to specify a debugger program in the debuggers's
>   settings. (For GCC compilers, it's 'gdb' (without the quotes))

The debug is selected in the CodeBlocks settings.

[Debug > Active Debuggers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a1eSf.jpg)

[In Settings > Compiler > Global compiler settings > Toolchain executables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zlEkb.png)

What seems to be wrong?

Comment: Is GDB *installed* on your Mac?

Comment: Yes, it is installed.